# Generate form for with csv format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am trying to use form for to specify two date fields, which specifies a timespan for data that I want to put inside a CSV file. I am able to create my csv file but I cant get rails to respond to csv format.

Here I have added my format: :csv in the form_for field, but it wont respond to that format in my controller.

```
<%= form_for(:estimation, html: {class: "estimations-form-horizontal"}, url: research_path, format: :csv, method: :get) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group-estimations">
    <%= f.label :from_start_date, "Från och med" %>
    <%= f.date_field :from_start_date, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group-estimations">
    <%= f.label :to_end_date, "Till och med" %>
    <%= f.date_field :to_end_date, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Hämta data", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

My controller, using format.csv ...

```
  def research
    if (params[:estimation] && params[:estimation][:from_start_date] && params[:estimation][:to_end_date])
      start_date = params[:estimation][:from_start_date].to_date.beginning_of_day
      end_date = params[:estimation][:to_end_date].to_date.end_of_day
      if(start_date > end_date)
        puts "Dates are in wrong order"
      else
        @estimations = Estimation.where(:created_at => start_date..end_date)
        puts to_csv(@estimations)

        respond_to do |format|
          format.csv { send_data to_csv(@estimations), filename: "skattningar-#{Date.today}.csv" }
        end

      end
    else
      puts "Not enough data"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> :url conflicts with :format If you are passing both :url and :format,
>   url overwrites the use of format, so you’ll need to pass it in the url
>   like so:
>
> ```
> form_for user, :url => user_path(@user, :format => :json)
> ```

[Source](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)