# How to create a dynamic csv export file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

I have create a simple csv export generator but looking to be able to pass created_at params to then export based on 2 dates and export the records in between the selected dates.

View:

```
<%= date_select :start_date, @start_date%>
<%= date_select :end_date, @end_date %>
<%= link_to("Generate Report", report_path(format: :csv) %>
```

Cont:

```
  def order_report
    @start_date = params[:start_date]
    @end_date = params[:end_date]
    @user_orders = Order.where(seller_id: current_user).where(order_status: 2).where(["date(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ? ", @start_date, @end_date])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @user_orders.to_csv, filename: "orders-#{Date.today}.csv" }
    end
  end
```

**model:**

```
def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << %w{ id created_at order_type order_price }
      all.each do |order|
        csv << [order.id, order.ctreated_at, order.order_type, order.order_price ]
      end
    end
  end
```

But the outcome is NULL:

> SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."seller_id" = $1 AND
>   "orders"."order_status" = $2 AND (date(created_at) BETWEEN NULL AND
>   NULL )

When i export, nothing exports but the headers.

How can I successfully do this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you when you click on any link, it sends get request. To pass parameter in get request, you need to use [query parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

There are many ways of passing parameters but I will show you simple path

Simple Solution is to replace your code to use form and submit

```
<%= form_tag report_path(format: :csv), method: :get do %>
  <%= date_select :start_date, @start_date%>
  <%= date_select :end_date, @end_date %>
  <%= submit_button "Generate Report" %>
<% end %>
```

If you don't want to use form, I can update the answer giving another solution.

Comment: Hm, that looks good if i update my controller.  I ended up doing something like this based off this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051223/generate-form-for-with-csv-format

Comment: So i tried doing the form_tag and got "can't quote ActionController::Parameters".... and as for not using a form; would you suggest a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please share the log?